# How to get DateTime from appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, appsettings

I have .net core 5.0 application and try to get DateTime from appsettings.json

appsettings.json:

```
"TimeModel": {
"RestartDuration": "27.10.2021 12:30:00"
 }
```

Code:

```
 services.Configure<TimeModel>(
            configuration.GetSection("TimeModel"));
```

Error:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to convert configuration value at 'TimeModel:RestartDuration' to type 'System.DateTime'.
   ---> System.FormatException: 27.10.2021 12:30:00 is not a valid value for DateTime.
   ---> System.FormatException: String '27.10.2021 12:30:00' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Comment: Start by storing your string representation of a DateTime in your AppSettings.json as ISO8601 - `"27.10.2021T12:30:00"`

Comment: @ZoharPeled dotnetfiddle also threw on that one. `"2021-10-27T12:30:00"` worked. Or `ParseExact`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/do45ki

Comment: @Fildor Of course you're correct. I don't know how I've missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways you could do it:

1. Get the date as a string, then parse it: `DateTime.Parse(configuration.GetValue<string>("Date"))`
2. You can get directly: `configuration.GetValue<DateTime>("TimeModel")`
3. You can use a class model.

In all cases, you need to make sure the date is in the format: `2021-10-27T12:30:00` by default.