# Hi can we configurable datetime in asp.net core app settings json

Tags: json, asp.net-core

Datetime configurable is possible on json app settings json

i try datetime for  startdate and enddate for search filtering it have done but i expecting configurable for datetime incase i change the days i only change on configurable it is possible please let me know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get DateTime from appsettings.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69736814/how-to-get-datetime-from-appsettings-json)

Comment: Could you please explan what exactly you are expecting here? Or could you please share your `code snippet` what you are trying to achieve?